# Calculate the mean value of pandas based on various features(columns)

Tags: python, pandas

## Goal

I am writing a card game analysis scripts. For convenience, the data was stored in the excel sheets. So users can type in the information of each game into the excel sheets and use the python script to analyze the return of the game. 3 rivals are involved in a card game (4 person in total), and I want to analyze the overall return vs a certain player. eg. I want to know how much my dad has won when play cards with Tom.

## Data

The excel sheet consists of several features like "date, start_time, end_time, duration, location, Pal1, Pal2, Pal3" and a target "Return" with positive number as gain and negative numbers as loss. The data was read using python pandas.

## Problem

I did not figure out how to index a certain pal, as he/she may in one of the column "pal#". I need to calculate the mean value of return when a certain pal is involved.

## Excel sheets(demo)

[image]

## Code

```
path = 'excel.xlsx'
data_df = pd.read_excel(path)
def people_estimation(raw_data, name):
    data = raw_data
    df1 = data.pivot_table(columns=['牌友1'], values='收益', aggfunc=np.mean)
    df2 = data.pivot_table(columns=['牌友2'], values='收益', aggfunc=np.mean)
    df3 = data.pivot_table(columns=['牌友3'], values='收益', aggfunc=np.mean)
    interest = (df1[name] + df2[name] + df3[name])/3
    print("The gain with", name, "is :", interest)
```

## Note

The code above achieve what I want. But I think there is a better way to do it. Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could `groupby` be useful to you? See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Use pandas [Pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) function with aggfunc="mean". you can also choose the features which should serve as columns and index

Comment: @rnso Simple `groupby` method does not work.

Comment: @2Obe I updated the code and  it works, but I guess there is a better way?

Comment: You should save this excel file as csv file and post here at least a part of it so that it can be used by users to help you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> a
   a  b  c
0  2  2  1
1  3  1  2
2  4  1  3
>>> mask = (a['a']==2) | (a['c']==2)
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
>>> a[mask]
   a  b  c
0  2  2  1
1  3  1  2
>>> a[mask]['c']
0    1
1    2
Name: c, dtype: int64
>>> a[mask]['c'].mean()
1.5
```

I think in your code it's wrong that condition for a mask should by in a bracket.

```
data[(data['牌友1'] == 'Tom') | (data['牌友2'] == 'Tom') | (data['牌友3'] == 'Tom')]['收益'].mean()
```

Comment: You got what I mean to do exactly. Thank you.